# How to create a Multicall Swap Multihop in JAVA based on Uniswap V3?

Tags: web3j, java, uniswapv3

Recently Uniswap And Pancakake swap launch thery v3 contracts, so the way of we do a swap changes now.

Is there someone that know how to do that in Java or Kotlin?

I'm asking for a Multihop, because The Token I'm testing has the liquidity in WBNB, so the patch in V2 are.. [Token1,Token2Liquidity,Token3final] and they dificult a lot with the custom fee on this field patch.

**I spend some days on it and I can't solve.**

```
val swapPath = listOf(Address(swapOutContract), Uint24(3000), Address("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"), Uint24(3000), Address("0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955"))

val params = listOf(
    DynamicArray(DynamicArray::class.javaObjectType, swapPath),
    Uint256(amountInMinInEther),
    Address(to),
    Uint256(deadline)
)

val function = Function("exactInputSingle",
    params,
    emptyList<TypeReference<*>>()
)
val encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function)


val multicallFunction = Function("multicall",
    listOf(
        Uint256(deadline),
        DynamicArray(DynamicBytes::class.javaObjectType, listOf(DynamicBytes(encodedFunction.toByteArray())))
    ),
    emptyList<TypeReference<*>>()
)
// Encode the multicall function call
val multicallFunctionCallData = FunctionEncoder.encode(multicallFunction)
```

[This are the documentation on PancakeSwap:](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/developers/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/v3-contracts/smartrouterv3/v3swaprouter)

[This are the documentation on Uniswap:](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/developers/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/v3-contracts/smartrouterv3/v3swaprouter)